# Magento, PHP form that sends an email

Tags: php, magento

I would like to send an email from a  magento/php form.

Can somebody please explain me how, lets say I have a form with 1 textbox and i need to send that in an email

Comment: Did you try using the built in Magenti contact form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: [Easily send email in Magento](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-send-email-easily-using-zend_mail/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you, it really helped a lot, the moderator closed the question hahahahahha, it was a programming question indeed.

Comment: You should really use Magento's built in template/email structure rather than defaulting to the Zend Mail class. Take a look at mage/email rather. @JeanCarlo

Answer (score 0):

I don't know magento so much but google [respond this](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/contact-form-in-magento/) may be help you.